# Unicode error in the tokenization step only when doing stop words removal in python 2

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, csv, unicode, stop-words

I am trying to run this script: [enter link description here](https://github.com/somul18/DeepMoji/blob/master/examples/score_texts_emojis_aw.py)
(The only difference is that instead of this `TEST_SENTENCES`  I need to read my dataset (column text). The only thing is that I need to apply stop word removal to that column before passing that to the rest of the code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['the "superstar breakfast" is shrink wrapped muffins that can be bought at a convenience store.',
                            'The wireless internet was unreliable. ', 'i am still her . :). ',
                            'I appreciate your help ', 'I appreciate your help '], 'sentiment':[
    'positive', 'negative', 'neutral', 'positive', 'neutral']})
```

***But the error does not raises when I use the data frame in this way but when I use the csv file that includes the exact same data the error raises.***

But when I add this line of the code to remove `stop_words`

```
df['text_without_stopwords'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word.encode('latin1', 'ignore').decode('latin1') for word in x.split() if word not in (stop)]))
TEST_SENTENCES = df['text_without_stopwords']
```

It keeps raises this error:
`ValueError: All sentences should be Unicode-encoded!`

Also, the error raises in the tokenization step:

```
tokenized, _, _ = st.tokenize_sentences(TEST_SENTENCES)
```

I want to know what is happening here that it causes this error, and the correct solution to fix the code.

(I have tried different encodings like `uff-8` , etc but non worked)

Comment: Is there a reason why you must use python 2? Are you able to give a sample dataset and required output?

Comment: @wwnde yea I have to stick with python 2. Its a GitHub project and it runs successfully when I do not do `stop words removal`.
The data is big and I guess just sharing 5 sample of data won't be sufficient to understand where this `unicode error` happens.right?

Comment: The point is that what is happening in that stop removal that causes this error. The code runs smoothly when I comment that line of the code!!

Comment: Still no luck! Any help is appreciated :(

Comment: Extract and provide a [mcve], as wwnde suggested!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Sure I just added. do you think that is enough?

Comment: Well, you can try yourself. Copy it from the question into a file and run that, it should produce the error you describe. So, obviously it's not. Maybe re-read the link?

Comment: The problem is that when I pass the data  in this way the error disappear, but when I pass the csv file with the exact same data it raises this error. Is there anyway I can upload the file here?

Comment: Well unfortunately its not possible. I just realized that the sample I shared here does not have any problem and the code can get run. However when I use the whole sample that error raises. So it seems there is a problem in some samples. Do you have any idea of what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reason yet but when I did

```
df['text_without_stopwords'] = df['text_without_stopwords'].astype('unicode')
```

it worked.

Still very curious to know why this is happening only when I do `stop words removal`